# Node.js async.series with existing functions

Tags: node.js

I'm struggling with the following problem. Say I have a wait function that takes a callback function (here foo) as an parameter:

```
function foo(data){
  console.log('foo says: ' + data);
}

function wait(count,callback) {
    console.log("waiting " + count + "s ...");
    setTimeout(function(){
      callback("just waited " + count + "s");
    },count*1000);
};
```

Calling wait(5,foo) returns:

```
waiting 5s ...
foo says: just waited 5s
```

I now want to use async.series where I first wait 7s and then 3s (i.e. 10s in total). It would be something like:

```
async.series([wait(7,foo),wait(3,foo)], function(err,result){ console.log(result); });
```

But for something like this to work, I would have to modify my wait function so that callback(null,"just waited " + count + "s") is called (instead of callback("just waited " + count + "s") and I also would have to modify the foo function (from foo(data) to foo(null,data)). Or is there a way to use async without modifying the existing functions?

Not: if I try `async.series([wait(7,foo),wait(3,foo)], function(err,result){ console.log(result); });` 
I obtain the following error:

```
node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3671
            task(rest(function (err, args) {
            ^

TypeError: task is not a function
```

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Yes, you need to call the callback according to the convention.

Answer (score 0):

I really think its a bad idea to use the async module to handle this. It used to be a decent solution a few years ago, but async/await keywords are now built into the latest Node, and if you *really* can't use the latest Node its not hard to add babel transpilation.

```
const delay = require('delay')

async function wait(seconds) {
  console.log(`Waiting ${seconds} seconds`);
  await delay(seconds);     
}

async function test() {
  await wait(7);
  await wait(3);
}

test().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was actually using wait as an example function. The problem I have is really about the need to change a functions's signature if I want to be able to use async.series and wondering if others have come accross that same issue and how they overcame it.

Comment: Don't use async.series. Its outdated and bad practice now.  Do it with async await and promises and you won't need to change the signature.